# Simple State Machine in Python

Tags: python, state-machine

im a rookie in Python and trying to build a state machine. My idea was a dictionary. So when i enter a key i get a value. And with that i would like to switch a function.

```
def one():
    return "January"

def two():
    return "February"

def three():
    return "March"

def four():
    return "April"

def numbers_to_months(argument):
    switcher = {
        1: one,
        2: two,
        3: three,
        4: four,
    }
```

but i dont know how i could go on. My goal would be to use the values to use the function with same name. Could anyone of you help me with a idea?

Comment: In what sense is this a state machine?

Comment: beginning of a state machine :), as i said still a rookie who is learning pyhton :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really a state machine, but what you probably mean is:

```
def numbers_to_months(argument):
    switcher = {
        1: one,
        2: two,
        3: three,
        4: four,
    }
    func_to_call = switcher[argument]
    func_to_call()
```

or perhaps

```
def numbers_to_months(argument):
    switcher = {
        1: one,
        2: two,
        3: three,
        4: four,
    }
    func_to_call = switcher[argument]
    return func_to_call
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly for what i was searching. Do you know any good State Machine types for rookies? I already searched for some but the explanation is often not easy to understand for a rookie

Comment: I think that you would be looking to make your own class. Check out this link: https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/StateMachine.html

Answer (score 0):

You can call any object in swicther with eval as well:

```
eval('switcher[1]()')                                                                                                                                                                             
# 'January'
```